# JavaScript date always returns "2015-11-1" instead of today's date

Tags: javascript

```
 var year = new Date().getFullYear();
 var month = new Date().getMonth();
 var day = new Date().getDay();
 var currDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

`New Date(`) will return today's date. Above code should return today's date like "2015-12-18", but it returns "2015-11-1". Anyone knows why? Thanks.

Comment: Note if you are unsure about the results always make sure to check the documentation for those functions. Don't assume what they do based on their names alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months are zero based, so you always have to add `1` to get the correct month.

```
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
```

or subtract `1` if setting it

`getDay()` is just the wrong method, it gets the day of the week, `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, `2` for Tuesday, and so on, not the date, that would be

```
var day = new Date().getDate();
```

Comment: One day, I want to be just like you <3

Comment: @PhiterFernandes - I know, everyone wants their own nuclear power plant.

Comment: the things I could do, the countries I could explode

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

`Date.getDay()` returns the day in the week (1 for monday - 0 to 6) so you need `Date.getDate()`

`Date.getMonth()` returns the month (0-11) so you need +1